# Authorization Header in HTTP Request

Tags: http, header, request, protocols, digest

So I am trying to replicate this http request:

```
GET /Login.asmx/Login%20 HTTP/1.1
Authorization: Digest username="****", realm="****", nonce="****", uri="****", cnonce="****", nc=00000001, qop="****", response="****", opaque="****"
Host: ****
Accept: */*
RETS-UA-Authorization: Digest f172df9efde8948e75fb54f76560921a
RETS-Version: RETS/1.5
User-Agent: *****
X-Librets-Version: 1.5.1, libCURL - libcurl/7.19.6 zlib/1.2.5
```

and am having trouble with what looks like the authorization header at the top.

```
GET /Login.asmx/Login HTTP/1.1
Host: ****
Accept: */*
Authorization: Digest username='****', realm='****', nonce='****', uri='/Login.asmx/Login%20', cnonce='MTM1Mjk0', nc=00000001, qop='auth', response='730caf960e18e42f1eb1f103c67b3ff4', opaque='7b227554-0ca3-4095-a6d0-ba5e1ed8c2eb'
RETS-UA-Authorization: Digest 458d81695fdf0f6063836b26cd287dbd
RETS-Version: RETS/1.7.2
User-Agent: ****
X-Librets-Version: 1.5.1, libCURL - libcurl/7.19.6 zlib/1.2.5
```

What my question boils down to is that I don't know what the authorization header in the working request really is (I use the term header but it may well not be). Any information or insight would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I reformatted your question so you can see the HTTP headers more clearly.  Now you can see the differences between the working request and your request.

Comment: Are you not getting the expected result? If so, what is the error?